# Trying to use Imagemagick's Mogrify to batch resize JPGs while retaining/cloning original directories

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick, image-resizing, mogrify

I'm trying to create a resized copy of a very large number of photos while retaining the directory structure that they came from. Here's what I have so far:

```
cd /d J:\Photos_test
for /r /d %%a in (*) do magick mogrify -path "J:\Resized_test" -resize 1920x1080^> "%%~a\*.jpg"
```

This takes any JPGs found in the subdirectories of `J:\Photos_test` and creates a resized copy in `J:\Resized_test`.

What I want to do is recreate the source directories while doing the resize operation. So, `J:\Photos_test\2018-04-19\133_PANA\P12345.JPG` would be resized and placed in `J:\Resized_test\2018-04-19\133_PANA\P12345.JPG`

How can I do this?

Comment: Aren't you going to get errors if files do not exist in a sub directory.  Why wouldn't you just use a `FOR /R` with a file mask of `*.jpg`.  We can show you how to create the relative path but your code just seems to inefficient that it would make more sense to fix that as well. Really confused as to why you are escaping the redirection?

Comment: I do not see a `-path` option on the [help website](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php)

Comment: I understand the escaping of the >.  But you shouldn't need to as the examples online say you should quote the argument. `-resize "1920x1080>"`

Comment: I had copied and adapted that from another example where someone was trying to grab JPGs out of folders and subfolders and convert them into PNGs in another folder.

I do get the following error, but it does copy and resize the JPGs that are in the subfolders:

`mogrify: unable to open image 'J:\Photos_test\2017-11-01\*.jpg': Invalid argument @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3375.`

Comment: I'm not very well-versed on this and I'm just feeling my way through based on examples I can find, so I'm probably not doing things in the most efficient way. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I got my brother to help me out a bit. This is what he came up with:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
title Batch JPEG Resizer

:: SOURCE FOLDER GOES HERE (NO FINAL \)
set "jpg_source=J:\Photos"

:: DESTINATION FOLDER GOES HERE (NO FINAL \)
set "jpg_destination=J:\Resized"

:: IMAGE RESOLUTION TO CONVERT TO (UNLESS SOURCE RESOLUTION IS SMALLER)
set "image_resolution=1920x1080"

cd /d %jpg_source%
set "relative_path=%cd:~2%"
for /f %%l in ('Powershell $Env:relative_path.Length') do (set relative_path_len=%%l)
for /r %%b in (*.jpg *.jpeg) do (set /a "jpg_count+=1" & echo !jpg_count!)
pause

for /r %%a in (*.jpg *.jpeg) do (
    set /a "current_jpg_number+=1"
    set "current_relative_path=%%~pa"
    set "current_relative_path=!current_relative_path:~%relative_path_len%!"
    if not exist "%jpg_destination%!current_relative_path!" mkdir "%jpg_destination%!current_relative_path!"
    if not exist "%jpg_destination%!current_relative_path!%%~na%%~xa" magick convert "%%a" -resize %image_resolution%^> "%jpg_destination%!current_relative_path!%%~na%%~xa"
    echo Image !current_jpg_number! of !jpg_count!: %%a
)

pause
```

This seems to do the trick! He added variables to make it easy to modify in the future and also included a counter and status readout. One last thing I'd like is to have the counter simply replace and update the echoed jpg_count number instead of writing it to a new line each time.

Comment: Put it in the Window Title: `TITLE Image !current_jpg_number! of !jpg_count!: %%a`

Answer (score 0):

I can't test the Imagemagick portion of your code as I can't load that on my work pc.

Essentially what I did was add in a check to see if JPG files exist in the directory before attempting to do any further processing on that directory.  If there are JPG files in the directory it then strips off the first directory from the file path.  It then creates that directory if it does not exist.  Finally it does your ImageMagick command.

```
@echo off
cd /d J:\Photos_test
REM get listing of folders
for /r /d %%G in (*) do (
    REM Check if there are jpg files in the folder
    IF EXIST "%%~G\*.jpg" (
        REM strip off the first directory from the input folder path and process the file
        REM The FOR variable %%I becomes the relative path. Folder Path minus the first directory.
        for /F "tokens=1* delims=\" %%H in ("%%~pG") do (
            REM If the folder does not exist create it.
            IF NOT EXIST "J:\Resized_test\%%I\" MD "J:\Resized_test\%%I\"
            magick mogrify -path "J:\Resized_test\%%I" -resize "1920x1080>" "%%~G\*.jpg"
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Smallest solution:

```
copy.bat on the origin folder:

XCOPY /S/D *.jpg  S:\icons\ 

XCOPY /S/D *.jpeg S:\icons\
```

`resize.bat` on the destination folder:

```
FOR /R %%a IN (*.jpg) DO magick convert "%%~a" -resize 600x200 "%%~a"
```